# Ubuntu14.04 - unable to apt-get update

Tags: apt, ubuntu-14.04

```
sudo apt-get update
```

returns some erors :

> W: Failed to fetch http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
>
> W: Failed to fetch http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
>
> W: Failed to fetch http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
>
> W: Failed to fetch http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
>
> W: Failed to fetch http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

### it seems to happen with the ubuntu official repo. Any idea why ?

For information, my sources.list is the following :

```
#----------------------------------------------------------#
#      OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPO                                #
#----------------------------------------------------------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                           UNOFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                            #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### 3rd Party Binary Repos

#### MongoDB - http://www.mongodb.org/
## Run this command: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may comes from your /etc/resolv.conf file, check if you have some `nameserver` directives on it and try to ping archive.ubuntu.com

Here is my resolv.conf :

```
domain local
search local

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

I use Google's public dns (https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/)

Then try apt-get update

Comment: For precision's sake, i didnt directly edited the _resolv.conf_ file because, as mentionned on the top line for ubuntu14.04, this would have been overriden. I instead edited `etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` then run the command `sudo resolvconf -u`

Comment: I have looked for this solution across the internet, your way was the best, fastest and easiest. it is much appreciated from a very new linux guy

Answer (score 1):

It detected some files it got were outdated or corrupted, so they were unusable.  Remove cached files by `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and try again `apt-get update.`

If the problem persists, maybe a caching proxy somewhere are still holding old or broken content. `apt-get update -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True` might help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try your local/nearest Ubuntu mirror.
I tested US DE FR mirrors and they all failed.
Changing to the local mirror solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind proxy? If yes then you have to go to `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file and modify that file as follows.

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxyaddress:portnumber/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@proxyaddress:8080/";
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but the only solution work out in this problem for me is:

Backup your sources list sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup

Open the sources file /etc/apt/sources.list and rename all the instances of us.archive from

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

to

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

Run sudo apt-get update after that.